# Unable to deploy Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, dacpac, sqlpackage

I am trying to deploy Azure SQLDatabase using SQLPackage.exe(DacPack Deploy) via Powershell.
While deploying dacpack(130) in region "**East US**", I get below error:

> sqlpackage.exe : *** Could not deploy package.
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (*** Could not deploy package.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   Unable to connect to master or target server 'TestDB'. You must have a user with the
>   same password in master or target  server 'TestDB'.

Same Database when deployed in "South Central US" region gets deployed successfully, but I want to deploy DB in "East US" region.

After installing DacFramework(140), Database gets deployed.

> But I want to know, is there any issues with Region?

How do I resolve this issue?

Thank You

Comment: Maybe this is a bug on Dac Framework. Let me share this thread and try to get some feedback.

Comment: Hi Amruta! A Microsoft Engineer is requesting to examine the PowerShell script. Could you share with us the script? If you need me to share with you an email address let me know. The Engineer is also asking me if you recently deleted a SQL Azure server with the same name on East US. He said that may explain the issue.

Comment: Hi Alberto, Thank you for your reply. Please share your email address so that I can share my script with you..

Comment: I received your mail and forwarded it to SQL Azure team for further investigation. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I received a response from SQL Azure team. They say the script is fine. They want you to open a support ticket. Is that possible for you?

Comment: Kindly share the answer if this issue was resolved.